# How do I set the POST headers of Play! 2.0 webservice query?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I am building a webservice request that submits some data to a 3rd party service we use:

```
val promise = WS.url("http://example.com/api/xxx/testers?api_key=%s" format(prefineryAPIKey)).post(requestBody)
val data = promise.value.get.body
```

The variable `requestBody` is XML content and I need to send this post with `"Content-Type: text/xml"`. How do I set that inside the webservice? Does it work like Play!'s result by chaining `.as("text/xml")`?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it! I had to dig around the API docs and decrypt some of the compiler errors, but basically the above will look like:

```
val promise = WS
  .url("http://example.com/api/xxx/testers?api_key=%s" format(prefineryAPIKey))
  .withHeaders("Content-Type" -> "text/xml")
  .post(requestBody)
```

When you call WS you are putting together a `WSRequestHolder`. The docs for WSRequest are here:

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.ws.WS$$WSRequestHolder